# How to loop this BASH statement correctly?

Tags: linux, bash

What is the best loop to use on this line of code I made, that goes through a log file and finds lines that are failed in `$6`?  Pretty fresh to BASH and LINUX and cant get any loop to work properly.

```
Sep 13 12:09:39 icarus sshd[14043]: Failed none for invalid user 55659
Sep 13 12:09:43 icarus sshd[14043]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 13 12:09:43 icarus sshd[14043]: pam_unix(sshd:auth):
Sep 13 12:09:44 icarus sshd[14043]: Failed password for invalid user 55659
Sep 13 12:09:48 icarus sshd[14043]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Sep 13 12:09:50 icarus sshd[14043]: Failed password for invalid user 55659 from
```

sample command

```
cat auth.log | sed -e 's/,//g' | awk -F" " '{print $6}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep Failed auth.log
Sep 13 12:09:39 icarus sshd[14043]: Failed none for invalid user 55659
Sep 13 12:09:44 icarus sshd[14043]: Failed password for invalid user 55659
Sep 13 12:09:50 icarus sshd[14043]: Failed password for invalid user 55659 from
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use awk:

```
awk -F" " -e '/Failed/ {print $0}' auth.log
```

There's no need for sed or cat.

Answer (score 0):

This looks for lines containing "Failed' (case-sensitive) and simply prints them,

```
awk '/Failed/ {print $0}' auth.log
```

I believe this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing `$6`, just print lines where `$6`  matches "Failed":

You had

```
cat auth.log | sed -e 's/,//g' | awk -F" " '{print $6}'
```

You can use

```
sed -e 's/,//g' auth.log | awk '$6=="Failed"'
```

(As others have pointed out, `sed` can take the file name as an argument, and `awk` breaks on whitespace by default, so there's no need to specify the `-F` argument.)

(Your sample input has no commas, so you may not even need the `sed` command.)